# Remove conditions from rails front-end html slim

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I have following code in my rails front-end `html.slim` file. I want to remove these nested `if-else` conditions. Can I implement this by moving these if-else conditions to some helper class?

```
  - if @current_task.task_type == 'econsent'
    - if @patient_organization.organization.identity_verification
      - if @patient_organization.manual_verified
        - if session['kiosk_token']
          = render "#{@current_task.task_type}_tasks"
        - else
          - if @reauthenticated
            = render "#{@current_task.task_type}_tasks"
          -  else
            = render 'relogin_required_screen'
      - else
        = render 'manual_verification_required_screen'
    - else
      - if @patient.self_verified
        - if session['kiosk_token']
          = render "#{@current_task.task_type}_tasks"
        - else
          - if @reauthenticated
            = render "#{@current_task.task_type}_tasks"
          -  else
            = render 'relogin_required_screen'
      - else
        - if @patient.self_verification_req_sent
          = render 'verify_email_after_sent_screen'
        - else
          = render 'verify_email_screen'
  - else
    = render "#{@current_task.task_type}_tasks"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to refactor those conditions, not just move them to another place. For ex: there is 5 different conditions that ends with `render "#{@current_task.task_type}_tasks"` you need to find what those have in comum, you don't need so many conditionals. Take a look at the usage of `if`, `elsif`, `else` and `unless`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could simply assign an `@to_render` variable in your controller action, something like:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController

  def bar_action
    ...
    @to_render = get_to_render
    ...
  end

private

  def get_to_render
    if current_task_type == 'econsent'
      if @patient_organization.organization.identity_verification
        if @patient_organization.manual_verified
          return :relogin_required_screen if (!@reauthenticated && !kiosk_token?)
        else
          return :manual_verification_required_screen
        end
      else
        if @patient.self_verified
          return :relogin_required_screen if (!@reauthenticated && !kiosk_token)
        else
          return @patient.self_verification_req_sent ? :verify_email_after_sent_screen : :verify_email_screen
        end
      end
    end
    return "#{current_task_type}_tasks".to_sym
  end

  def kiosk_token?
    session['kiosk_token']
  end

end
```

Then in your `html.slim` file, do:

```
= render @to_render
```

I can't remember, but you may need to do:

```
= render "#{@to_render}"
```

since `@to_render` will be a symbol. Doing the string interpolation will automatically convert the symbol to a string.